Gravity form calculate the sum last entry by a user
I am using gravity form, I want to sum the last entry of a form by a user. Ie. a form A is Dept A is submitted by a user, Form B in dept. B submitted by user A, I want to sum a field of form A from Dept with Form B in Dept B. It is only the last entry that I want to sum
I have tried gravity maths, gravity count but not success.
Any suggestion or Code would be helpful

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

SELECT user_id, form_id, SUM(field_value) AS total_value
FROM entries e
WHERE (e.user_id, e.form_id, e.created_at) IN (
SELECT user_id, form_id, MAX(created_at)
FROM entries
GROUP BY user_id, form_id
)
GROUP BY user_id, form_id;

If this is the supporting code that the community member requested, you can add it to your question by clicking "edit".
If this is the solution to the problem you ran into, you should put the code in a code block and refactor it for legibility.
